# Classical logistic regression VS Firth logistic regression: comparison in power

Tags: logistic, references, statistical-power, regularization, bias

I understand that in case of separated data, logistic regression via ordinary MLE has an upward bias in the p values, which implies that any penalized MLE designed to reduce this bias will have more power in such cases. Specifically I'm considering Firth's penalization.

Can someone point me to a reference or an argument that compares the power of Firth logistic regression to ordinary MLE *in general* (that is, without the assumption of data separation)?

Answer (score 0):

With some more research I found this article where several methods are compared for power amongst other features, and they find that Firth regression has a power comparable to ordinary GLM:

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-82547-z.pdf

Comment: The too-large-p-value problem applies when unadvisedly using the Wald $\chi^2$ test.  If you use the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test, complete separation is not a problem, and Firth's approach is not needed.